# android - can't access view inside fragment method. it returns null object

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, view, nullreferenceexception

I'm building an app based on the tabbedActivity preset of android studio ,therefore fragments are created so:

```
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

and later on:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    DashboardTab tabDashboard = new DashboardTab();
                    return tabDashboard;
                case 1:
                    VertretungsplanTab tabVertretungsplan = new VertretungsplanTab();
                    return tabVertretungsplan;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Dashboard";
                case 1:
                    return "Vertretungsplan";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this is all working fine but in fact it is quite an uncommon way of creating tabs so it might be that my problem is caused by a missunderstanding of the MainActivity.java

```
public class VertretungsplanTab extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertretungsplan_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }



    public void setText(String textToBeSet, VertretungsplanTab tab){
        TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
```

now the problem is as far as i now caused by the view, because it is a null object inside my method.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

I've tried several ways of accessing the view, which includes creating a new variable in this fragment and commiting the view to it in onCreateView().
Also if I checked it in onCreatedView() it wasn't yet a null object.

I've also tried to create the TextView in onCreateView(), but after onCreatedView() it isn't possible to call setText()

After searching the internet several days it would be a great help if a more advanced developer could get a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay basically its not clear from your question that where you wanna call `setText()` method. It would be better if you've added that place from where you want to call `setText()`.

But as far as i could understand your situation, you must've calling the method outside of your fragment and you must be creating an object of your fragment. If you call `setText()` method from inside your fragment say in `onViewCreated()` then it would 100% work but if you try calling the method like this:

```
VertretungsplanTab tab = new VertretungsplanTab();
tab.setText("any text", tab);
```

It will definitely return you with a `NullPointerException` because you've created a new object of the fragment and as we know an object is just a blueprint of your class that means it doesn't have the values after any modification into it.

I've used Fragments a lot and have also faces these situations many times. If you have another class that want's to update the text inside your Fragment, Handlers are the best choice you have.

`BroadcastReceivers` are also not a bad choice for such situations and you can also use interfaces or abstract classes for this. Just try to learn these concepts because these are the best thing that you have when you want to pass your data from one class to another.

An example for using Interfaces is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161081/7071039). This is just an example, it's not similar to your problem but through this you will get an idea of using interfaces. Just go through it..i hope it will help.

You can also learn how to use Handlers to pass data from activity to fragment or fragment to activity.

If i'm getting your question wrong then please explain in more detail because this is the most that i can understand from your question :)

Comment: Well, this is exactly what i was trying to do :)
Thank you very much, it was a great help!

Comment: @Tarun Chauhan can you please explain what did you mean by `it doesn't have the values after any modification into it.` As when creating the object I am inflating the Layout and getting a reference to my view. So why it is returning null?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `Fragment` transactions are asynchronous, so normally you shouldn't access `Fragment` from your activity. What you should do instead is to pass all the necessary data via `.setArguments()` when creating Fragment in `getItem` method. And later on in `onViewCreated` you can access the `Bundle` you passed in before with `getArguments` call:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            DashboardTab tabDashboard = new DashboardTab();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("USER_NAME", users.get(position));
            tabDashboard.setArguments(bundle);
            return tabDashboard;
        case 1:
            VertretungsplanTab tabVertretungsplan = new VertretungsplanTab();
            return tabVertretungsplan;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then in `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.findViewById(R.id.textView2).setText(getArguments().getString("USER_NAME"));
}
```

Check example with passing data to `DetailsFragment` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier that way :

```
public class VertretungsplanTab extends Fragment {

private View rootView;
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertretungsplan_fragment, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    return rootView;
}



public void setText(String textToBeSet, VertretungsplanTab tab){
    tv.setText(textToBeSet);
}
```

Comment: In this case `tv` is null for me :'(